# fb:loggin-button gets stuck

Tags: javascript, facebook, xfbml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [IE FB.login callback not running and XD proxy window left open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9291374/ie-fb-login-callback-not-running-and-xd-proxy-window-left-open)

I'm using facebook javascript sdk to allow logins on a website trough facebook.

What happens is that on IE and Opera it gets stuck on a blank page whenever i try to login via facebook (http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect/xd_proxy.php?...)
this has an js error message

```
User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0; Trident/5.0; SLCC1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; .NET CLR 3.5.21022; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)
Timestamp: Tue, 31 May 2011 16:00:01 UTC

Message: No such interface supported

Line: 89
Char: 7
Code: 0
URI: http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect/xd_p … ?version=2
```

Line 89 is:

```
relation.postMessage(fragment, params.origin);
```

I was able to resolve the issue on Opera using suggested code after FB.init():

```
if($.browser.opera ) // it uses jQuery library here!
{
   FB.XD._transport="postmessage";
   FB.XD.PostMessage.init();
}
```

But in IE the only way I was able to get over this was uninstalling flash activeX that seems to create the conflict, but this is not a viable solution since i can't ask all the website users to uninstal their flash players.

Anyone faced this and got arround it or get any solution or suggestion on what to do?