# IE FB.login callback not running and XD proxy window left open

Tags: javascript, facebook

I am having problems getting Facebook login to work correctly in IE. The problem is intermittent. Usually, when it makes the call to FB.login, the popup appears but stays on an empty white page, XD proxy, and never runs the callback. Occasionally, the callback will run, but the window will not close - I think this may be the first time I try it after rebooting my machine (closing and opening the browser does not have the same effect).

You can see this problem on [www.runescape.com/](http://www.runescape.com/index.ws), yet with the same code on [www.waroflegends.com/](http://www.waroflegends.com/index.ws), the login seems to work correctly.

I have searched and found a lot of talk on the XD Proxy topic, but none of the solutions seem to work for me. I have tried adding a custom channel url and making sure the fb div is the first child of the body to no effect.

Answer (score 0):

I've been experiencing the same issue in IE9, and it seemed to stem from upgrading to Flash Player 10. I'd lost hope in trying to fix it since finding an [open bug at Facebook](http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=12112) covering it. But [Henson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/229424/henson) has posted [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9256756/575530) that fixed it for me. In the JavaScript in my site master I removed the lines

```
    FB.UIServer.setLoadedNode = function (a, b) {
     //HACK: http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=20168
     FB.UIServer._loadedNodes[a.id] = b;
    };
```

and now it works. (N.B. I have not checked to see if the IE8 issue those lines were intended to overcome returns.) If that's not it take a look at some of the answers suggested in [FB.login dialog does not close on Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6125254/575530)

Answer (score 0):

Try this right after FB.init:

```
if($.browser.msie || $.browser.opera) { // yes, this is jQuery :)
  FB.XD._transport = 'fragment';
  FB.XD.Fragment._channelUrl = yourChannelUrl;
}
```